# How to take text from one place then render at other place on same page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xhtml

```
<div id="default">
<h2> heading </h2>

<div id="big-on-hover">
<h2> heading </h2>
```

I want to render the text of `h2` of `<div id="default">` in `<div id="big-on-hover">` because both will be same always so I will change at one place it will show all other places also.

Comment: On what event do you wish to update it?

Comment: @amit - on hover. I mean on mouse enter. on mouse enter upon "default" , "big on hover" will be seen.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('#default h2').mouseover(function() {

            var text = $('#default h2').html();
            $('#big-on-hover h2').html(text);
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understood it correctly this is what you want.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#default').hover(function(){
        var hoverhtml = "<h2>" + jQuery('#default h2').html() + "</h2>" + jQuery('#big-on-hover').html();
        jQuery('#big-on-hover').html(hoverhtml);
    },
    function(){
        jQuery('#big-on-hover h2').remove();;
    });
});
```

Comment: I want to add <h2> on hover don't want to keep before.

Comment: You will need a placeholder to append the h2 on hover. Like a div or something in its place.

Comment: I want to add same `h2` of "default" as a first thing inside `<div id="big-on-hover">`

Comment: I modified it. Should do what you need.